# Converter número romano em decimal

Tags: java, string

Estou fazendo um exercício onde preciso converter um número romano digitado, e o programa retornar um número decimal.

Meu algoritmo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumerosRomanos {

    public static void main (String args []) {

        System.out.println ("Digite um Número em Romanos, para saber qual é esse Número em Decimais");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        String numeroRomanoInicial = sc.nextLine();

        String numeroRomano = numeroRomanoInicial.toUpperCase();

    System.out.println(verificarNumerosRomanos(numeroRomano));
    }

    public static int verificarNumerosRomanos (String numeroRomano) {
        int digitoRomano = 0;
        int digitoRomanoemconjunto = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<numeroRomano.length(); i++) {
        digitoRomano = numeroRomano.charAt(i);    
            switch (digitoRomano) {
                case 'I': digitoRomano += 1;
            break;
                case 'V': digitoRomano += 5;
            break;
                case 'X': digitoRomano += 10;
            break;
                case 'L': digitoRomano += 50;
            break;
                case 'C': digitoRomano += 100;
            break;
                case 'D': digitoRomano += 500;
            break;
                case 'M': digitoRomano += 1000;
            break;
            default: System.out.println("Dígito Romano Errado.");
            }
        }
            int soma = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i<numeroRomano.length(); i++) {

            char dr = numeroRomano.charAt(i);
            char drSeguinte = numeroRomano.charAt(i+1);

                if (dr == 'I' && drSeguinte == 'V') {
                    digitoRomanoemconjunto += 4;
                } else

                if (dr == 'I' && drSeguinte == 'X') {
                    digitoRomanoemconjunto += 9;
                }
                else

                if (dr == 'X' && drSeguinte == 'L') {
                    digitoRomanoemconjunto += 50;
                } else 

                if (dr == 'X' && drSeguinte == 'C') {
                    digitoRomanoemconjunto += 90;

                } else 

                if (dr == 'C' && drSeguinte == 'D') {
                    digitoRomanoemconjunto += 400;
                } else 

                if (dr == 'C' && drSeguinte == 'M') {
                   digitoRomanoemconjunto += 900;
                }
            }
            soma += digitoRomano + digitoRomanoemconjunto;
            return soma;
    }
}
```

Gera erro de `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Como corrigir este erro?

Comment: Pode adicionar a pilha de erro completa na pergunta também?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Esse erro está na linha:

```
char drSeguinte = numeroRomano.charAt(i + 1);
```

Que pode resolver com:

```
char drSeguinte = i < numeroRomano.length() - 1 ? numeroRomano.charAt(i + 1) : ' ';
```

Tem maneira de fazer mais eficiente, mas vou no trivial para não confundir com conceito novo.

Mas o código tem problemas de lógica. O que está fazendo aí não tem muito sentido. O cálculo está fazendo errado, mas esse é outro problema que não é o foco da pergunta.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Q0c9hT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/isdsbhbx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/RomanConversion.java).

Comment: Muito obrigado. Você pode responder qual é exatamente o problema de lógica, e como consertar?

Comment: Não é um, o código todo não faz o que deve, então ele não calcula corretamente. Não consigo imaginar porque tem 2 laços, porque existe essa lógica do "seguinte", pelo menos da forma como está não gera os valores corretos.

Comment: Certo. Realmente dá erro mesmo. E como fazer para fazer o código correto?
Teria que usar If´s ou Switch cases, certo?

Comment: @InicianteemJava Sim, claro, mas aí já é outro problema. Essa pergunta está respondida, se tiver outro problema precisa abrir outra pergunta. Aqui é um site de perguntas e repostas objetivas. Não é um fórum, então cada problema é uma pergunta. Dê uma olhada no [tour].